# SublimeCodeIntel : could not find Python blob 'gtk'

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

I'm having some troubles using SublimeCodeIntel with Python. For example :

```
 self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
 self.window.set_title("Mega Connector") 
 self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)
 self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
 self.window.set_border_width(10)
 self.window.
```

When SublimeCodeIntel tries to find out what functions can apply to that object, it returns me this : `could not find data for Python blob 'gtk'`
And it does the same with every function I'm trying to us it with.
I'm using Python2.7 and `import gtk`.
Actually my code works fine, but the autocompletion seems not to work. I don't know why, could someone explain me why ?